# Unable to get the remote servers details by pinging using Shellscript

Tags: csv, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

Unable to fetch the remote server details by pinging the servers:

```
$servers = Get-Content C:\Users\list.txt
$collection = $()
foreach ($server in $servers)
{
$status = @{ "ServerName" = $server; "TimeStamp" = (Get-Date -f s); "NSLookUp" = (nslookup -a $server) };
if (Test-Connection $server -Count 1 -ea 0 -Quiet)
{ 
    $status["Results"] = "Up"

} 
else 
{ 
    $status["Results"] = "Down"
}


New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
$collection += $serverStatus

}
$collection | Export-Csv C:\Users\status.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

unable to get the remote server details from this **"NSLookUp" = (nslookup -a $server)**

Any suggestion ....... guys

Comment: I tried your script, substituting out-gridview for export-csv, and it worked. I do see errors from nslookup due to the -a parameter, but it still worked. Maybe your hosts aren't known by the DNS server you have configured.

Comment: are you getting the details of remoteServer address, actually I am getting thi result: "System.Object[]".

Comment: I'll add what I'm getting as an answer. Comments don't have the formatting control necessary

Answer (score 0):

I tried your script, substituting out-gridview for export-csv, and it worked. I do see errors from nslookup due to the -a parameter, but it still worked. Maybe your hosts aren't known by the DNS server you have configured

Here is the output using FT. I'm just showing the NSLookup property here, otherwise it's hard to read.

```
$collection|ft -auto
    NSLookUp                                                                              
    --------                                                                              
    {Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com, Address:  8.8.8.8, , Name:    google.com...}
    {Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com, Address:  8.8.8.8, , Name:    ibm.com...}
```

BTW, I'm using PS 3.0

Edit: When I use export-csv I do see system.object[].

I think I see the problem. The .NSLookup member is an array of lines. You need to convert it into a single string. Something like:

```
$last = $collection.count -1 
0..$last | % {$collection[$_].nslookup = -join $collection[$_].nslookup
```

Answer (score 0):

change :
`$collection = $()` to `$collection = @()`

change:

```
New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status -OutVariable serverStatus
$collection += $serverStatus
```

to

```
$collection += New-Object -TypeName PSObject -Property $status
```

what does `nslookup -a $server` do...does this run at the command prompt?
you get system.object[] in the output when the element is an array instead of a string.